# How to schedule a MySQL Event on every XX:50 Seconds?

Tags: mysql, database

I Have a MySQL table with field name result. I want to use a event to execute **on every XX:50** seconds and update the value of field by a random number.

Need help regarding the syntax for every XX:50 seconds.

I have tried this query.

```
CREATE EVENT `testEvent` 
ON  SCHEDULE EVERY 50 SECOND 
DO BEGIN

SET @A := (SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `table`);

UPDATE `table` SET `field` = (RAND()*18) WHERE `id` = @A;   

END
```

using this query first update is done on 00:00:50 then next update will be done on 00:01:40, 00:02:30 and so on.

but i want to execute it on 00:00:50, 00:01:50, 00:02:50 and so on..

Answer (score 11):

[MySql events](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html)

To execute an update every 50 seconds:

```
CREATE EVENT myevent
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 50 SECOND
DO
   UPDATE yourdb.yourtable SET yourcolumn = RAND();
```

To do it every 2 min and 50 seconds:

```
CREATE EVENT myevent
ON SCHEDULE EVERY '2:50' MINUTE_SECOND
DO
   UPDATE yourdb.yourtable SET yourcolumn = RAND();
```

Use `SHOW PROCESSLIST` to check if event scheduler is enabled. If it's ON you should see a process "`Daemon`" by user "`event_scheduler`".
Use `SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;`to enable the scheduler if it's currently not enabled.
More on configuring event scheduler [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-configuration.html)

Answer (score 0):

Too late for OP, but may be of use to someone else in future.

If you want your event to be executed `EVERY XX:50` seconds, then you want it to be executed `EVERY 1 MINUTE` with the start time offset by 50 seconds:

```sql
CREATE EVENT `testEvent` 
ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY 1 MINUTE
    STARTS DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:50')
DO
    UPDATE `table` SET `field` = CEIL(RAND() * 18) WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM (SELECT MAX(id) id FROM `table`) t);
```

If the datetime is `2023-10-09 10:36:53` when the event is created, the `Starts` value for the event is set to `2023-10-09 10:36:50`, which is in the past. The first execution will still maintain the correct time offset and be at `2023-10-09 10:37:50`.